# Tossing a fair coin $N$ times, what is the variance?

Tags: probability

$X$ is a random variable that equals the number of heads.
$E(X)$ is the expected value of the number of heads when a coin is tossed $n$ times, so since $P(X)= 0.5, E(X) = \frac n2$

I know that the variance is calculated by $V(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$, but my question is how would I calculate $E(X^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical example of a [binomial experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), in short the probability distribution of the variable $X$ can be written as

$$
P(X = x) = {n \choose x}p^x (1 - p)^{n-x} \tag{1}
$$

in your case $p = 1/2$ is the probability of getting heads when the coin is tossed. And from here you can do the math to show

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_x x P(X = x) = np
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{V}{\rm ar}[X] = \sum_x (x - \mathbb{E}[X])^2 P(X = x) = np(1 - p)
$$

Comment: okay thank you, is the formula np(1-p) for the variance something that I can use in any problem?

Comment: @OliverBeck **If** the problem is binomial, then yes. Otherwise you cannot start applying this result to every problem you find.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate $\mathbb EX^2$ purely on base of the equality:$$\mathbb EX^2=\sum_{k=0}^nk^2P(X=k)$$

If you take that (cumbersome) route then it is handsome to make use of: $$\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^nk(k-1)P(X=k)+\sum_{k=0}^nkP(X=k)=\sum_{k=0}^nk(k-1)P(X=k)+\mathbb EX$$

However you are dealing with a random variable $X$ that has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=\frac12$. Then it is much more handsome to write $X=B_1+\cdots+B_n$ where the $B_i$ are iid random variables having Bernoulli-distribution with parameter $p=\frac12$.

Then with linearity of expectation, symmetry and independence we find:$$\mathbb EX^2=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nB_iB_j\right]=n\mathbb EB_1^2+n(n-1)\mathbb EB_1\mathbb EB_2=n\cdot\frac12+n(n-1)\cdot\frac12\frac12=\frac14n+\frac14n^2$$leading to $\mathsf{Var}X=\frac14n+\frac14n^2-\left(\frac12n\right)^2=\frac14n$.

If you are aiming only at variance and not specifically $\mathbb EX^2$ then there is even a faster route:$$\mathsf{Var}
X=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathsf{Var}B_k=n\mathsf{Var}B_1=\frac14n$$

This because the variance is also linear under the extra condition that the terms are independent.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Given the random variable $X$ and its corresponding probability mass function $f_{X}(x)$, we have

$$\textbf{E}(g(X)) = \sum_{x}g(x)f(x)$$

Comment: sorry but I am unfamiliar with the probability mass function, is it necessary here to find the variance?

Answer (score 0):

There is some misunderstanding in your model, because you mixed up one single toss with the whole experiment.

**The right model:**
You have $n$ random variables $X_i, i=1,\dots,n$ which are identically and independently distributed. Each $X_i$ returns $1$ if you toss head and 0 else. Therefore the distribution is given by
$$
P(X_i = 1) = 0.5 \quad\text{and} \quad P(X_i = 0) = 0.5 \quad\text{for all} \quad i \in \{1,\dots,n\}.
$$
The random variable $X$ which counts the number of heads is $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. Therefore, you have $P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k}\cdot 0.5^{n}$.

Now remember that $\mathbb{E}(Y) := \sum_{i\in Y^{-1}(\mathbb{R})} iP(Y=i)$ (for discrete random variables)